# Getting error while loading properties file within the executable jar when running on linux server

Tags: java, linux, windows, executable-jar

I am loading the properties file within the jar, when i run this jar in the windows machine it is working fine. But when i run the same executable jar in linux server it is failing getting below error:
"Unable to execute command due to error: null/AutoTest/auto_env.properties (No such file or directory)"
Below is the code written to load the properties file:

```
InputStream in = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("/auto_env.properties");
Properties props = new Properties();
try {
    if (in != null) {
    props.load(in);
}
```

I tried below fixes to solve the issue but it did not work:

1. To get the properties file path: `getClass()..getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI().getPath()` and passing it in the inputstream.
2. Instaed of `Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()` used ClassLoader.class that also din't worked.

Please help to resolve this

Comment: What is 'fileInputStream' ? your code has 2 variables: in, props

Comment: By mistake it should be in variable

Comment: Have you tried using the class loader of 'this', instead of Thread.currentThread ? The Thread object likely to come from a (system) class loader, which does not have access to the JAR resource. 'this.getClass().etClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(...)

Comment: The leading 'null/' in the error message indicate that the code was not able to resolve the leading path from the class loader. Your Linux box might have tight permission (security manager) vs. You Linux box